# Asterisk: Outgoing and incoming calls from a PC

Tags: asterisk

In my project I am stuck with a requirement related to the tele calling module. The requirements are something as :

Outgoing Calls:

1. The calls made must be computer operated (one click of the mouse).
2. The system, at the time of calling, should be able to show the last conversations with the called party in text form.
3. Details such as called by, the conversation (in .wmv file), phone picked up or not (flag value), timing of the call, duration of the call, type of call(internal or external) and other should be placed in the DB in such a manner so that it can be extracted easily in a programming language (to be specific, Java)
4. All the conversations should be saved in .wmv file.

Incoming Calls:

1. The system should be able to detect the caller from the database and hence present the data on the screen.
2. The system should be able to detect the location of the caller.
3. The system should link to the database of the respective caller with the call and at a time give all the relevant information of the caller if it is present in DB.

Other requirements:

The system should be intelligent enough to work with Simple dedicated Phone line, IP phone and IVRS system (specifically IVRS DX-2000); two at least.

I would be really thankful to you if you can help me in this.

Comment: Dont downvote this question. Its a pain to get started, let alone explain and form a question.

Answer (score 0):

I think these pages can be helpful for you:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+extensions.conf

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517342.do

But actually it would be better to hire an asterisk professional.

Comment: Asterisk boasts of ability to configure without too much know how. The introduction video sounds like scam to me. Its so damn crazy to understand simple things. And yet we confidently downvote.

Comment: I can say same for any complex system.

Comment: Not true, untangle for example is a complex firewall solution, but claims to be easy to use and configure. And its stands up to the challenge. There are "NO" tools outside of untangle that make untangle any easier. Asterisk on the other hand boasts of easy configuration, but in reality the documentation and the product itself talks about a hell a lot of acronyms. They even have tutorial sessions for sale, come on!!! There are 1000s of companies out there trying to make asterisk easier. Its a pain in the ass to start with. That said, its a good stable product. I just hope I could get it started

Comment: that is man-specific. someone understand voip,some not. i not understand your problem, if you can't understand but need it, hire teacher/go courses. or maybe it is just not your field.

Comment: Cant argue with that. Can you recommend any good getting started kinda sites. I have looked like hell.

Comment: Book on link above is good enought. If read it carefully and not too fast.